# Making a 1040 ES tax payment on the installment plan

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

Imagine a hypothetical person has a $1000 1040 ES payment due on Jan 15. The person was planning on making the payment using EFTPS. However, the person prefers to make payments of $200 dollars 5 times. Would it be okay if person make weekly payments of $200 through EFTPS starting around Dec 1? I am thinking it should be but normally you only make one 1040 ES payment a quarter? Will the IRS object?

Comment: Since EFTPS can't know what you (will) owe, only what you decide to pay, I'm sure you can make as many payments as you want and whenever you want as long as the total is sufficient and they're not after the deadline. But why? Since you necessarily have a bank account, why don't you just put the money in the bank account and pay it on Jan. 15 or maybe a day or two before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EFTPS is required for business taxes, but is not the most convenient option for individuals. You're probably thinking of "Direct Pay" feature on the IRS website.

If you want to pay in installments, you'll need to [apply for a payment plan](https://www.irs.gov/payments/online-payment-agreement-application). Alternatively you can use your credit card to make the payment and pay off the credit card debt as you see fit (you cannot pay with credit cards [using EFTPS](https://www.eftps.gov/eftps/direct/FAQGeneral.page#serviceWork)).

If you don't have an approved payment plan, you'll need to pay in quarterly payments per instructions. You can [amend a quarterly estimate payment](https://blog.turbotax.intuit.com/self-employed/how-do-i-amend-my-previous-quarterly-estimated-tax-payment-31613/), however there's no explicit amendment process. You can follow the article and try to use it in order to "de facto" pay in installments, but that may invite some scrutiny from the IRS if they determine you're doing it intentionally (up to claims of fraudulent return, which is a felony).

Comment: I have been using the following website to make my 1040 ES payments (personal) for many years: https://www.eftps.gov/eftps/ I have not had any problems, Therefore, I conclude that they can be used for personal tax payments. However, I have only been making 1 payment per quarter.

Comment: @Bob EFTPS *can* be used for any tax payments, but using the IRS Direct Pay is much simpler. EFTPS is *required* to be used for any business taxes. So while sure, you can make your life more complicated that you need to, most people don't.

Comment: An installment agreement/plan only applies to debts that have been _assessed_ -- i.e. after the end of the year when you file a return, or later when/if IRS does a substitute for return, or applies a penalty or interest. For estimated payments IRS doesn't yet know what you will owe -- even you may not know -- so it's impossible to compute installments. Estimated payments are not a return, even if you use the paper form 1040ES which you don't with electronic payment, and can't be fraudulent, only sufficient or insufficient to avoid penalty for underpayment.